# chrome://kill Not working when used in a Bookmark and in the address bar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, crash

I've been trying to purposely crash Google by using `chrome://kill`, but it doesn't do anything. The page works just fine and i dont understand.

I tried every `chrome://` link that crashes it, but they dont work! Does anybody else know whats going on?

Comment: When I use it in the address bar I get a page that says "Aw snap! Something went wrong". What do you get instead?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.